# 500 Server Error on Smart Capture Form

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I have created a CloudPage with a Smart Capture form that writes to a data extension, form renders with no problems, but on submission of the data, Google Chrome console shows a 500 server error, no errors are shown in ExactTarget. Pretty new to this platform so please let me know if you need any further information.

CloudPage can be found at https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/afw1r5bkbte

This page was built using the new Content Builder within ExactTarget.

Comment: Please add the JSON-Response of the request that returns the HTTP 500 error. Sometimes there is additional information which helps debugging the issue.

Comment: Thanks @MarkusSlabina, where would I find this JSON response? The page was built using the Content Builder within SalesForce

Comment: In the Google Chrome developer tools under "Network" you should see the failed route and clicking on it will show details. The exact response can be found with a further click on "Response". For this to work, you need to open the developer tools before submitting the form.

Comment: Response view only has the HTML of the 500 error page. The only JSON I have is in the request data

Comment: What fields comprise the primary key on the target DE?  What about the field data types and precisions?  Are they appropriate for your inputs?

Comment: Spot on @AdamSpriggs one of the DE fields had too short a length. Thanks for your help, feel free to add this as the answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd bet that you're violating the primary key or that your inputs don't match the data types and precisions configured in your Data Extension.

Comment: omg the error feedback is so terrible, spend multiple hour, finding out i had af bool field, but wrote a string into it