# Debugging DE submission AMPScript on a landing page?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, debugging, landing-page

I have a landing page that is intended to collect data from a form and send it to a data extension when the form is submitted. Currently the page is not working and redirects to the stock 'internal server error' page when submitted, so I'm pretty sure there's at least one bug in the code - but I can't find any way beyond guesswork to work out where said bug is.

I have seen error messages on other questions that go into some detail on where things go wrong - is there still a way to access this, and if so how?

Code in question:

```
%%[
Var @Email, @Forename, @Surname, @News, @Products, @Equipment, @Colas, @Energy, @Waters, @Juice, @Organic, @Adult, @SendToDE

Set @Email = RequestParameter('email')

IF RequestParameter("submitted") == "submitted" then

Set @Forename = RequestParameter('Forename')
Set @Surname = RequestParameter('Surname')
Set @News = RequestParameter('News')
Set @Products = RequestParameter('Products')
Set @Equipment = RequestParameter('Equipment')
Set @Colas = RequestParameter('Colas')
Set @Energy = RequestParameter('Energy')
Set @Waters = RequestParameter('Waters')
Set @Juice = RequestParameter('Juice')
Set @Organic = RequestParameter('Organic')
Set @Adult = RequestParameter('Adult')


Set @SendToDE = UpsertData(
'GB_CX_Preferences',
1,
'Email', @Email,
'Email', @Email,
'First Name',@Forename,
'Last Name',@Surname,
'NewsTradeCat',@News,
'ProdOffComp',@Products,
'EquDispSol',@Equipment,
'Carbs',@Colas,
'Energy',@Energy,
'Waters',@Waters,
'Juice',@Juice,
'Organic',@Organic,
'Adult',@Adult)

ELSE

Set @Forename = Lookup('GB_CX_Preferences','First Name','Email',@Email)
Set @Surname = Lookup('GB_CX_Preferences','Last Name','Email',@Email)
Set @News = Lookup('GB_CX_Preferences','NewsTradeCat','Email',@Email)
Set @Products = Lookup('GB_CX_Preferences','ProdOffComp','Email',@Email)
Set @Equipment = Lookup('GB_CX_Preferences','EquDispSol','Email',@Email)
Set @Colas = Lookup('GB_CX_Preferences','Carbs','Email',@Email)
Set @Energy = Lookup('GB_CX_Preferences','Energy','Email',@Email)
Set @Waters = Lookup('GB_CX_Preferences','Waters','Email',@Email)
Set @Juice = Lookup('GB_CX_Preferences','Juice','Email',@Email)
Set @Organic = Lookup('GB_CX_Preferences','Organic','Email',@Email)
Set @Adult = Lookup('GB_CX_Preferences','Adult','Email',@Email)

endif
]%%
```

Relevant section is before the ELSE, I think.

Comment: Please share your code here. Only then we will be able to debug.

Comment: Please find a similar issue raised here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164854/500-server-error-on-smart-capture-form

Comment: @KratiGarg added my code to the question. It might be a primary key issue since I am using email as a primary key and 'updating' it (with the existing value, so nothing actually changes) in my upsert statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're including Email in the WHERE statement but also in the INSERT statement.

Logically, when you're writing an UPSERT, if the Email address is not in the data source it will INSERT, but if it is, then it will UPDATE.

Try running your UpdateData without the second 'Email' insert and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to update the row with a parameter and then you are querying to update that parameter too. And it is not because that parameter(email in your case) is a primary key. Even if you try to update a row using forename and then try to update forename in the same function, it will throw an error.

And because the UpsertData function gets executed at the run time, the cloud page throws error.

So, please remove the second Email and  the code will work.